# Including the output of one web app in another

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, include

There are 2 web applications(webapp1 and webapp2) hosted inside the same tomcat. Webapp2 UI is a HTML page. Is there a way to include this entire webapp2's output in one of the pages of webapp1?

Tomcat webapps looks like this:

```
webapps
 |-webapp1.war
 |-webapp2.war
 |-webapp1
 |-webapp2
```

webapp1 is accessible via an URL which looks like:

```
http://localhost:8080/webapp1
```

webapp2 is accessible via an URL which looks like:

```
http://localhost:8080/webapp2
```

webapp1 UI is Struts2 based. To describe it in a simple way, it has several main buttons which when clicked load related jsps on the remaining real estate of the browser.

**Requirement is when one of these main buttons is clicked, in the remaining real estate of the browser webapp2 must be loaded.**

webapp2 is a single jsp webapp.

Comment: Yes, there are some ways to do that. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am not sure of the direction to take. Some google pointed me to cross-context communication and some of its alternative approaches. But since I am looking for including the entire web app in another it looked like they might not be the ones needed.

Comment: Well, the simplest way to include one webapp into another is using the `IFRAME` tag. Or are the two webapps expected to communicate?

Comment: The 2 webapps must be able to communicate. on clicking of one item in webapp1, data must be launched in webapp2

Comment: Well, _data must be launched_ - how? As URL parameters? In such case an IFrame is still the easiest option. If webapp2 expects the data as POST parameters, it would be more complicated. And, of course, there is still a possibility to extend webapp1 to "proxy" the webapp2, using e.g. [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/index.html) and stripping the unnecessary html headers etc.

Comment: the data in the page is html data.

Comment: Would you mind to edit your question and add a simplified example? Because it seems we are using the same terms for different things.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek, edited the question to add more info. thanks for the help.